# If $|A \cup C|$ = $|B\cup C|$ and $A,B,C$ are pairwise disjoint, are infinite sets |A| = |B|?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assume ● $A,B,C$ are nonempty sets and
● $A\cup C$ and $B\cup C$ are numerically equivalent and
● $A\cap C=B\cap C=\emptyset$.

Prove or disprove that $A,B$ are numerically equivalent.

Intuitively, for a finite set $A,B$, the statement should be true. But when considering  infinite sets, then I don't know how to prove or disprove it.

Edited: "Denumerable" has been changed to "numerically equivalent."

Comment: Exactly what definition of *denumerable* are you using?

Comment: Edited, it should be numerically equivalent

Comment: I have never seen the term "numerically equivalent". What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By hypothesis there is a bijection $h:A\cup C\to B\cup C$, $A\cap C=B\cap C=\varnothing$, and you want to show that there is a bijection from $A$ to $B$. If you were lucky enough to find that $h[C]=C$, you’d be done, because then $h[A]$ would have to be $B$, and $h\upharpoonright A$, the restriction of $h$ to $A$, would be a bijection from $A$ to $B$. Unfortunately, there’s no reason to hope that $h[C]=C$. If $C$ is infinite, $h[C]$ might be a proper subset of $C$, and then we could easily have $|A|>|B|$.

In fact, if $C$ is infinite the result is false; here’s a counterexample. Let $C=\Bbb Z^+$, the set of positive integers, $A=\{0\}$, and $B=\Bbb Z\setminus\Bbb Z^+$, the set consisting of $0$ and the negative integers. Then $A\cup C=\Bbb N$, $B\cup C=\Bbb Z$, and

$$h:\Bbb N\to\Bbb Z:n\mapsto\begin{cases}
\frac{n}2,&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
-\frac{n+1}2,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}
\end{cases}$$

is a bijection from $A\cup C$ to $B\cup C$. Obviously, however, $A$ and $B$ do not have the same cardinality.

Answer (score 2):

If by numerically equivalent you mean the same cardinality, all you can conclude for infinite $C$ is that $|A| \le |C|$ and the same for $B$ or that $|A|=|B|$ (in which case they can be larger than $C$).

Comment: Did you mean to say that either $|A|=|B|$ or both $A$ and $B$ must have cardinality at most $|C|$? Clearly $A\cup C$ and $B\cup C$ have the same cardinality if $|A|=|B|=\aleph_0$ and $C=\emptyset$.

Comment: @MartinSleziak:  you are right.  I read the infinite case to imply that $C$ was infinite, but even there they could be larger if they are equal cardinality.  I'll add it.